# Hybrid auth flow in .NET Core WebApi project with SPA

Tags: angular, oauth, .net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I'm working on a project, and it's my first encounter with an SPA with API architecture (as well as my first .NET Core project).  I'm trying to figure out how the authentication/authorization flow should work, as it's sort of complicated.  The identities will be provided by on-prem ADFS via OAuth.  The Angular frontend redirects to the ADFS login page, and it redirects back to the SPA with the "code" parameter, which the app then posts to a controller method in the API backend.  The API then calls back to ADFS and exchanges the auth code for a token, and then validates the token against the signing certificate.

Here's where I'm getting a little fuzzy on how to proceed.  The API uses ASP.NET Core Identity, and we need to define "local" (to the application) roles that will be applied to the users of the system.  The Angular app needs to be aware of these roles, so I'd like to pass them along in the JWT going back to the client.  Is it possible to "augment" the token from ADFS to include additional claims?  Should I just create and issue a different token associated with the local user and use that for the duration of the session?

Basically at a high level what i'm confused about is what the relationship is between the "identity" token coming from the IdP that I will use to actually authenticate the user and the token that the angular app will use to sign its API requests (which I suppose will also need to authenticate the user).  In a simpler model I assume you could just use the same one for both, but if there are any best practices for this type of scenario.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"identity" token or `id_token` is for authentication.

"access" token or `access_token` is for authorization.

So when you login via your ADFS, with the Angular client, it will return both the `id_token` and `access_token` and maybe a `refresh_token` depends on how it's configured for this particular client. Your ADFS should be configured to store whichever claims you would like in your `access_token` things like `name`, `email`,`role` etc...

When you call your API with the Angular client it will attach the `access_token` to the header (sign the request). The API then has to validate the token with the ADFS. The API should be asking is this client allowed to access me? and if so whatever claims the `access_token` has can be used in whatever way. You cannot use the `id_token` to sign requests because it is used for authentication with the ADFS and not authorization with the API.

Comment: The response I'm getting back from ADFS at the token endpoint *only* contains an access token: `
{"access_token":"...","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600}
}`

Comment: @lmerry213 look up how to extract claims from the access token on your API